# How to get Hash value of an object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

How to get hash value of an object in typescript.

For example :

```
let user:any = {name:'tempuser', age:'29'};
let anotheruser:any = {name:'iam', age:'29'};
if( Object.GetHashCode(user) === Object.GetHashCode(anotheruser)){
   alert('equal');
}
```

also we can identify the object whether it is modified or not.

Comment: JS objects don't have hash codes (unless you implement one).

Comment: Ya.. That's why I posted here for help. Please let me know if you have any library to get hash value  of an object.

Comment: google is a better place to search for such a library. SO doesn't do library recommendations.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, neither JavaScript nor TypeScript provide a generic hashing function.

You have to import a third-party lib, like [ts-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5) for instance, and give it a string representation of your object: `Md5.hashStr(JSON.stringify(yourObject))`.

Obviously, depending on your precise use case, this could be perfect, or way too slow, or generate too many conflicts...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to compare the objects and not the data, then the @Valery solution is not for you, as it will compare the data and not the two objects.
If you want to compare the data and not the objects, then JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2) is enough, which is simple string comparison.

Comment: no, don't compare JSON.stringfy results - https://betterprogramming.pub/why-you-shouldnt-use-json-stringify-to-compare-objects-in-javascript-c9a16b7331e

Answer (score 5):

For non-crypto uses, like implementing a hash table, here is is the typescript of the venerable java hashCode of a string:

```
export function hashCode(str: string): number {
    var h: number = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return h & 0xFFFFFFFF
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but if I understand it correctly you're just looping through your string then turning each char into a charcode right? Does this actually have any advantage over simply stringifying and comparing? It's more than likely that I've missed something but it feels like this just adds an additional processing overhead.

Comment: @K-Dawg, You should read the question. The question is how to get a hash code.

Comment: @doug65536 yes but sometimes we have to step back and try to think about what the OP is actually trying to achieve. Perhaps they've made assumptions leading them to a sub-optimal solution for the given problem? 

Either way, passive-aggressive phrases like "You should read the question" don't help. So let's try to keep the platform friendly and not mock each other for simply sharing our thoughts.